# Trying to save a file in illustrator but it will only save the text and graphic and none of the white space

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to save a square image from illustrator. The background is totally white, with just black text and a black graphic in the centre. When I export it, it is only exporting the area which has the text and graphic. How do I save the WHOLE image?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant you want to export your artwork, not saving your AI file.
The white background is not an object, it's your artboard. So, you can either create a white object that you place behind your graphic (which would be a better practice since this white block is part of your graphic) or, if you use "Save for the Web" feature, tick "Clip To Artboard Size" option.
Note that if you use PNG format, you also need to untick "transparency".

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! I used save for web and ticked clip to art board size, which did save it how I wanted, except now it's super pixelated. Can you tell me whats happened here? It's 300x300px

Comment: Check your parameters. Do you save as JPEG? check quality (minimum 60%). If PNG, use PNG24 instead of PNG-8. To make a long story short, play around with parameters. Please provide screenshots if you still can't do it...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I saved as PNG. Will look at parameters, thank you!

Comment: I still can't fix it. Here is a screen shot on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9v91d2x6g3s9q75/Screen%20Shot%202017-01-31%20at%2019.25.52.png?dl=0

Comment: That's a pretty small screenshot but if the result is too pixelly make the source file vector at 1200 x 1200. If in all your saving you ever saved it in a raster format (.jpg, bmp, gif) it will be pixelly. If your original .ai file looks good and you export a vector file type (.png. .pdf, .svg) than it will look sharp at any size.  Even with vector art I make them way bigger than my final result and reduce it in that "save for web" dialogue. If it was at 1200 px to begin with I'd reduce it by entering 25% in the resizer thingy.